# What is the French word for “cuteness”?

Tags: traduction

What is the French word for “cuteness"?

Comment: If you believe random words can be translated from one language to another without taking any context into account, you are very much mistaken.

Comment: Words rarely have "official translations". Words expressing concepts have no magic property either that would free them to require a context to be properly translated. Moreover, a very clear definition in one language doesn't mean it would be equally clear in another.

Comment: Jolie has joliesse. Therefore, does mignon have migonnesse? Is it a word written in a dictionary like the Académie Française or is it a word which people understand and use but is not written in a dictionary?

Comment: The other way around. *Mignon* has *mignonnesse* which is "official" according to your definition because mentioned in several dictionaries (e.g. Littré, TFLi) but it would be a poor translation of "cuteness" because while the English word is common, the French one is so rare that it would be considered improper and unsuitable by most native speakers.

Comment: Well, that depends on the context... Words are rarely used without any.

Comment: Well, why don't **you** provide actual sentences where cuteness is used and show your attempts to translate them into French? By the way, Zekovsky's answer clearly shows that being present in a dictionary doesn't prevent native people to believe a word is a made up one.

Comment: [What do French people use [..]?", You take the suffix **ness**, and you get:  **l'état, la condition ou la qualité d'être mignon/mignonne** or any one of them. Not everything is at it seems. And, furthermore, pour enfoncer le clou: cuteness in English, is as odd as what I provided in French. If you were writing a paper on "cuteness", you'd probably use "le mignon" in French. But that's another story. Elle démontre cette qualité d'être mignonne que l'on ne voit pas souvent.....[And side note to mods: Hmm, who needs to be sent one of those warning emails?? Tsk, tsk.]

Comment: I've cleaned up the comments a bit. I left a few that I think were somewhat useful. I think the different points have been made sufficiently.

Comment: @Perplexed The suffix comes from translating the English:  ness = state, quality or condition into French. My idea has nothing at all to do with the erie ending in French....Translation is about translation of meaning, not a one-to-one equivalence of words....

Comment: @Lambie Thank you. :) I just wanted to know where mignonnerie came from.

Comment: Suffixes : [-erie](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/-erie), [-itude](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/-itude), [-ité](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/-it%C3%A9). But consider children might be cute differently than a nose, because one could be endearing and the other aesthetically pleasing. But that is absent from just stating the word, because that's context. You can have a word that's not in use for a 1:1 equivalent of sorts, or you can actually translate to French depending on context. Surely there will be some _mignon_ therein, but there's much more.

Comment: @AmandeAdorable I'm sorry for my behaviour. I was mistaken. Thank you for this info.

Comment: I apologize for my words and behaviour. Probably the truth is there somewhere in the middle. Anyways, your questions are welcome. Best of luck.

Comment: @Perplexed By the way, you are welcome to visit our [chat] which is more suitable for discussions like the one we just had than comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Mignon" is the translation for "Cute", but cuteness doesn't really have one.

You can either use made up words like "Mignonnerie".

Or you can say that it is cute. "C'est mignon." "C'est trop chou !"

But it might be different from what you need depending on the context in which you want to use this. Did you have a particular sentence or idea in mind ?

Comment: @Perplexed Then as stated in my answer, there is no literal translation as far as I know, aside from made up words.

Comment: In this context you can replace "cuteness" with made up words given here by people or by myself. Or you can replace it with "être mignon" which makes it a tautology.

Comment: La définition de la qualité d'être mignon, c'est sa condition.

Comment: ***Mignonnerie*** and for that matter the better ***[mignonnesse](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/mignonnesse)*** are not made up words, assuming words listed in a dictionary are not.

Comment: Seems like it is a difficult subject because I can't find them in the online Larousse.

https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/Mignonnerie

What is the dictionary you use on your website ? I'd like to know why it is in there and not elsewhere. (The Académie ones below don't seem to have them either.)

Answer (score 2):

I think "mignonnerie" is a possible translation but it not a word really used in French.

I probably would translate it by "côté mignon".

Comment: *Mignonnesse* would probably be closer than *mignonnerie*, although equally rare.